# How to format negitive numbers into parenthesis?

Tags: java

I am working on a program that uses multiple classes to function. The goal of this program is to search a list/collection to retrieve information on different chemical elements. We need to format the atomic mass in a 3 decimal format that also puts negative numbers inside parenthesis instead of showing the - symbol.

```
final public static DecimalFormat commasThreeDecimals = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.000");
```

right now this does format the number into 3 decimal places. I realise there is nothing in the code to change the - to ().

Comment: Can we see some example inputs and outputs? Off-topic: how can atomic mass be negative? Are you studying anti-matter? :P

Comment: elementObj = new Periodic_Elements_Class(47,"Ag","Silver",107.87, "Solid");
 elementsList.add(elementObj);
 elementObj = new Periodic_Elements_Class(79,"Au","Gold", 196.97, "Solid");
 elementsList.add(elementObj);
 elementObj = new Periodic_Elements_Class(99,"Es","Einsteinium",252, "Synthetic");
 elementsList.add(elementObj);
 elementObj = new Periodic_Elements_Class(102,"No", "Nobelium", 259, "Synthetic");
 elementsList.add(elementObj);
 elementObj = new Periodic_Elements_Class(107,"Bh", "Bohrium",-262,"Synthetic");
 elementsList.add(elementObj);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern to show negative numbers in parenthesis

```
 final public static DecimalFormat commasThreeDecimals = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.000;(###,###,###.000)");
```